# Diagnosing and correcting hop on carbon wheel

Tags: wheels, carbon, rear-wheel, wheel-building, wheel-truing

NOTE - please read update below and all comments.

I have a Mavic Cosmic carbon wheel which is perfectly true, but it has some vertical hop (3-4 mm). I thought at first that it was out of round, but deep carbon rims are very strong and rigid, and I don't see how it's possible for it to bend.

I did a test to check the roundness of the wheel - I measured the radius at different points around the wheel (from the hub to the outside of the rim). It was 306 mm all around. So the wheel is round, right?

I took the quick-release axle out and rolled it along a flat surface - I noticed that it is slightly bent, maybe 1 mm max deviation. I guess this is at least partially contributing to the hop, but I don't think it fully explains it. I will replace the axle - hopefully that corrects the issue, but if not, what else could be contributing to it?

**UPDATE**

I've replaced the quick-release skewer. The wheel still hops, so at least it's eliminated that possibility.

Here's a video showing the hop. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0ZxM.jpg

I've also noticed there is a slight raised area at the edge of the wheel at one point. This is on both sides, like the wheel edge is slightly "flared" at that point. This is very slight but enough to alter the braking force at that point - I can feel pulsing through the brakes as the friction increases at this point. Looking at the wheel rotating again, it seems to pull in sharply at this point. So it's like the opposite of hop - what's that, dip? This causes the excessive rubbing and you can see the brake marks below:

[image]

Comment: Get a new axle. Should be easy to buy and nothing exotic. Mavic isn't exactly the smallest back-yard company.

Comment: @Carel It's a Novatec axle, but yeah I will get it replaced. I should clarify, when I say axle I mean the Quick-Release rod.

Comment: quick release rods are generally called skewers if this helps to disambiguate the question

Comment: Is the bead seated evenly all the way around?  This seems like a long shot, but you appear to have dealt with the likely causes.

Comment: I would note that when I notice a "hop" while riding the bike the first thing I check is that the tire is evenly seated all around.  Especially check the area near the valve, as the tube tends to get caught under the tire beads there and cause this problem.

Comment: But in your video the wheel is clearly not properly "trued".  You need to take it off, put it in a truing stand, loosen most of the spokes, and start the truing process over again.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It's laterally trued, as in the brake pads stay a constant distance from the wheel, but yes, not radially trued, which is, well, why I posted this question.

Also, you can see that it's the wheel that's hopping, not the tyre.

Comment: @Kev - Yep, "truing" the wheel means to have it true in both dimensions.  From the looks of it, either you have some broken spokes or the original truing was botched.

Comment: @DanielRHicks no broken spokes - I replaced them all to try and correct it, but no luck. It's possible the original truing was botched, as I bought the bike 2nd hand, but I had not really noticed this until recently. It's also possible that I botched truing the new spokes. I've actually just slackened off all the spokes, and the hop is still present, albeit less pronounced. The wheel could be damaged I guess. I'm getting pretty tired of this and I may just take it to a shop, assuming any are open.

Comment: If you replaced the spokes without using a truing stand, that would account for your problem.

Comment: @DanielRHicks maybe, but the problem was present before and after the replacement, and is still there with all the spokes loosened. Does this indicate wheel damage?

Comment: @Kev It's possible that the rim is damaged, but proper truing should be able to correct much of the out-of-roundness that I see in the video.

Answer (score 4):

By 'hop' I assume you mean radial run-out (as opposed to lateral run-out).

A bent axle will have no effect on the rim running radially true or not, because the hub rotates around the static axle. A slightly bent quick release shaft will just conform to the bore through the axle and have no effect.

A rim can be perfectly circular but still have radial run-out - if the hub axis is not at the center of the circle. That may be what is going on here. In any case the solution is to have the wheel re-trued.

Comment: Note that Kev said "I measured the radius at different points around the wheel (from the hub to the outside of the rim). It was 306 mm all around," which means it's much less likely the case that the hub is not centred.

Comment: Yes, radial is what I meant.